# Chemistry.SE is now in public beta!

Tags: discussion

Just a quick word to let you know that [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) has now launched into public beta!

Comment: I flagged because this is not answerable.

Comment: This question appears to be obsolete.